# How to load images from a folder in sequence based on the number on the images name

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

I want to make a program to show images 1 by 1 every second based on the frame number in **sequence** (the images come from a video and i already change it into images .jpg with 292 frames), but there's some error that make my program to show it 1 by 1 but **not** in sequence, sometimes its jumped (from frame 1 to 100) and sometimes its not.

```
import glob
import cv2

img_location = 
'E:\\User\\Programming\\Python\\Work\\asd\\*.jpg'
img_loc = sorted(glob.glob(img_location))
for img in img_loc:
    print('processing %s...' % img,)
    img = cv2.imread(img, 0)
    cv2.imshow("img",img)
    cv2.waitKey(250)
```

Comment: sounds like you sort the numbers lexicografically.

Comment: sorted() sorts strings lexicographically, 1,10,100,11,12 ... and so on, you need to extract the number from the filename and sort it as a integer.

Comment: i named my images only with number

Comment: Still string. Have to convert to integer

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will try what you suggest !

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is naming your file with the suffix 0. For example: 001, 002, ... 100, 101, ... 250

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to d0 something as follows

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_location = 'E:\\User\\Programming\\Python\\Work\\asd\\*.jpg'
img_loc = sorted(glob.glob(img_location))
img_numbers = [int(iloc.split(".")[0]) for iloc in img_loc]
sorted_indices = np.argsort(img_numbers)

for sorted_img_idx in sorted_indices:
    print('processing %s...' % img_loc[sorted_img_idx],)
    img = cv2.imread(img_loc[sorted_img_idx], 0)
    cv2.imshow("img",img)
    cv2.waitKey(250)
```

What this does this it assumes naming of files is as follows: 1.jpg 2.jpg and so on, we then strip the .jpg, and convert "1" to int, then we apply argsort, that returns an array of indices that correspond to a sorted array, then we just iterate through all indices and display the in sequence images

ALTERNATIVE AND EASIER WAY:

If the naming convention is as mentioned above then simply just do

```
base_path = 'E:\\User\\Programming\\Python\\Work\\asd\\
img_names = [ base_path + str(img_number) + ".jpg"  for img_number in range(1,101)
```

and then iterate through it and display the images

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg can play folder with pictures.
You can create:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:\\User\\Programming\\Python\\Work\\asd\\%d.jpg', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

or

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:\\User\\Programming\\Python\\Work\\asd\\%d.jpg', cv2.CAP_IMAGES)
```